# How to map a function key in (console) vim

Tags: vimrc

I'd like to map a function key (f.i. F7) to have quickly the **gggqG** format command; i'd like to place it permanently in my .vimrc and working in console (not in gvim). I red some literature, but I was not able to solve. Any suggestion? Thanx

Comment: this largely depends on the terminal-emulator in use. It should work with `<f7>` for xterm out of the box. same for linux-console.

Comment: at present here I'm using gnome-console

Comment: echo $SHELL tells me /bin/bash

Comment: $SHELL is not relevant here. Look for $TERM and `:set term`

Comment: samiel@darkstar ~ $ $TERM
xterm-256color:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply put `map <f7> gggqG` into your .vimrc. It works out of the box for most
terminals, including xterm and xterm-256color

Comment: yes, it was so simply.... working!

Comment: Teach a man to fish: [`:h key-notation`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-notation) :)